# Does `mount -a` cause already mounted filesystems to be remounted, or are they ignored?

Tags: filesystems, mount

Does `mount -a` cause already mounted filesystems to be remounted, or are they ignored?

https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount's `mount -a [-t type] [-O optlist]` doesn't mention what is done for already mounted filesystems (or perhaps I missed it):

> (usually given in a bootscript) causes all filesystems mentioned in fstab (of the proper type and/or having or not having the proper options) to be mounted as indicated, except for those whose line contains the noauto keyword. Adding the -F option will make mount fork, so that the filesystems are mounted simultaneously.

Comment: If there a partition cannot be mounted `mount -a` will return an error message. And if you want to view all mounted partitions you can always use `df -h`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mounted filesystems will be ignored. As of 2.33.1 the [man page](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/mount/mount.8.en.html) states:

> The exception is
> --all, in this case already mounted filesystems are ignored (see  --all
> below for more details).